# Remove access to abc from my module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I've created a Python module file that looks like this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Engine(ABC):
    # Rest of class
```

This gives the unwanted side-effect of a user of my module being able to do this:

```
import my_module

class SomeClass(my_module.ABC): # Use ABC from my_module!
    # Rest of class
```

**Is there a way to stop a user from accessing `ABC` and `abstractmethod` from my module?** The only way I can come up with is to change my file structure to something like this:

```
--my_module/
----__init__.py
----engine.py
```

and then in `__init__.py` do  `from engine import {everything but ABC etc.}`. Of course this doesn't actually fix the problem per-se since the user can still do `my_module.engine.ABC`.

Comment: Why do you want to restrict the access to your abstract class?

Comment: Python has no working security model to reliably prevent some module from accessing objects in other modules in the same Python process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I don't want to restrict access to my abstract class I want to restrict access to the abc module from my module.

Comment: @Blender I've read about __ all __ but as the answers to that question states it only works when you use `from my_module import *`. You can still do `from my_module import ABC` and so on.

Comment: okay, my bad - why do you want to restrict access to `ABC` from your module?

Comment: @Charanor: You can delete all your imported objects with `del` at the end of your file if they bug you. `__all__` is useful for the scenario you describe at the end of your question, since the `{everything but ABC etc.}` part can just become `*`.

Comment: What is the reason makes you wan to restrict access to `ABC` module?

Answer (score 2):

The typical approach that I've seen is to do something like this:

**`engine.py`**:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

__all__ = ['Engine']

class Engine(ABC):
    # Rest of class


del ABC
del abstractmethod
```

**`__init__.py`**

```
from engine import *
```

Most projects that I've seen don't bother to clean up the imported globals, since they will not be exposed by using `__all__` with the `__init__.py` that imports everything. There's nothing wrong with doing it, though.

If you don't clean them up, the only way a user will be able to see them is if they bypass your module and import those objects from your submodule directly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the critical problem is why you need to restrict **developers**?

As python supposes that developers are smart enough to handle security problems about module access and namespace, it doesn't provide any reliable methods to restrict access.

And why you need to restrict person to access `ABC` module? If you are worrying about variables overriding which may caused by `from xxx import *`. You can just use `__all__ = [...]` to specify what you want to export.

`requests` is a really well-formed library, but it still doesn't make any efforts on unneeded restricting access.

Comment: And that's really useful for when you want to monkey patch requests without having to copy the entire library and edit it.